# Trying to catch the exitcode from PowerShell Invoke-command with a BAT file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to catch the exitcode from a PowerShell script that uses a Invoke-Command to run a scriptblock on a remote machine.

First the BAT file:
The BAT file is run with a variable. The script looks like this:

```
powershell.exe -noninteractive -noprofile -command "& {E:\Scripts\Check-Services_XXX.ps1 %1 }"
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

The PowerShell script looks like this:

```
param(
[string] $ip #IP address van server
)


$username = "DOMAIN\DOMAIN_USER"
$secpasswdfile = "E:\Location\DOMAINUSER_encrypted_password.txt"
$secpasswd = Get-Content $secpasswdfile | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpasswd)
$soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipRevocationCheck -SkipCNCheck

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip -UseSSL -SessionOption $soptions -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock `
{
# Start services
Start-Service -InputObject (Get-Service -Name IAS)

# Check services status

$checkservice = (get-service -Name IAS -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
if($checkservice.status -ne "Running"){$host.SetShouldExit(1)}

exit
}
```

The problem is that the ExitCode is not captured back, so when the BAT file ends, it ends with 0. That would be the case if everything is running. But i deliberately changed the service name in the check service section to something that does not exist for sure, but still it the BAT file ends with Exitcode 0

Done so far: Tried this solution:
[catching return code of a command with "invoke-command" - Powershell 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210942/catching-return-code-of-a-command-with-invoke-command-powershell-2)
But didn't work: got the following error "is not equal to Open, you cannot run a command  in the session.  The session state is Closing"
Apparently, when it exited with a error, the session was closed, thus couldn't get the exitcode

Also tried this one: [Capture Write-Host output and exit code from Invoke-Command on a Remote System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524103/capture-write-host-output-and-exit-code-from-invoke-command-on-a-remote-system)
But also the same result; no correct exitcode (expected 1 instead of 0 in the BAT file)

**SOLUTION!**

Thanks to @js2010 and @mklement0 ; it works now like a charm!

This is the BAT file:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -File "E:\Scripts\Check-Services_XXX.ps1" "%1" "%2"
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

And here is the PowerShell code that eventually worked out for me:

```
param(
[string] $ip,       #IP address of checked server
[string] $service ) #Service name

$username = "DOMAIN\USER"
$secpasswdfile = "E:\Scripts\Credentials\DOMAIN-USER_encrypted_password.txt"
$secpasswd = Get-Content $secpasswdfile | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpasswd)
$soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipRevocationCheck -SkipCNCheck
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -UseSSL -SessionOption $soptions -Credential $credentials

# Start services
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Start-Service -Name $using:service }

# Check services status
$checkservice = Invoke-Command -Session $session { Get-Service -name $using:service | where status -eq running }
if (! $checkservice) { 
  write-output ("Error 1, Service '" + $service + "' not running or not found.")
  exit 1
}
```

I had some issues with passing variables to remote commands, this link helped me out (https://powershellexplained.com/2016-08-28-PowerShell-variables-to-remote-commands/)

Comment: Yes! it worked guys! Thank you so much guys!

I got it working now.

Comment: @js2010; thank you for helping me out on this!

Comment: @mklement0; thank you for helping me out on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to run the exit command outside of invoke-command.

```
# check-service.ps1
$result = invoke-command localhost { get-service appxsvc | 
  where status -eq running }
if (! $result) { 
  exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your invocation of `powershell.exe` to use the `-File` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -File "E:\Scripts\Check-Services_XXX.ps1" "%1"
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

That way, the `.ps1` script's exit code is properly relayed as `powershell.exe`'s exit code.

Additionally, as [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687732/45375) notes, you'll need to use your `$host.SetShouldExit(1)` call *out of the `Invoke-Command` script block*, given that the latter executes *remotely*. For the reasons explained below, `exit 1` is preferable.

---

Generally speaking:

- There's no reason to use the `-Command` (`-c`) CLI parameter with `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.
- **Not only is `"& { ... }"` unnecessary, it invariably *resets the exit code to `0`*.**

As for your use of `$host.SetShouldExit(1)` to request exiting with an exit code of `1` (leaving aside that in a *remote* call it isn't effective):

- It generally isn't designed to be called from user code, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60774177/45375).

For general information about exit codes in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).